# WPF Listview: How to change background of an ListViewItem in CodeBehind?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF ListView with a simple data binding:

```
<ListView Name="MeasurementListView">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="MeasurementListView_Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="MeasurementListView_Color" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Color}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

I bind it, as soon as it is loaded from the database and the user click the button load:

```
    private void FillMeasurementListView()
    {
        MeasurementListView.ItemsSource = this.myData;
    }
```

Now the Color column is a RGB information (e.g. 200, 200, 200) which I can cast into a System.Drawing.Color easily.
So at the moment the text is displayed (200, 200, 200) but instead I want to hide the text and color the background of this ListViewItem in the given RGB color.

So without a databinding (Im new to WPF and MVVM though) I would look for an entry point where the data is loaded (e.g. a loaded-event), find my cell / column and empty the displyed text and set the background color, Sadly I can't find such and event in this ListViewControle.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the style for Item:

```
<ListView Name="MeasurementListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="MeasurementListView_Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="MeasurementListView_Color" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Color}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color, Converter=ColorToBrushConverter}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

ColorToBrushConverter - IValueConverter to convert your type's Color property to a Brush type (SolidColorBrush).

---

Or without a Converter, if the **Color** property is of type **System.Windows.Media.Color**.:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```